# Splitting polygon into separate polygons using table of individual lines

Tags: postgis, polygon, sql, splitting

[image]

I have been trying for a while but have not been able to split a polygon at multiple locations, using a table of lines, to get what is on the right side of the above image.

The best I can achieve is the large polygon being split at one of the locations. My query is below:

```sql
drop table if exists new_polygons;
CREATE TABLE new_polygons AS
SELECT ST_Split(a.geom, b.geom) as geom
FROM large_polygon as a, blades as b
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom);
```

Comment: do those lines intersect within the polygon, creating areas?

Comment: Yes they do. This problem is also on a large scale, occurring numerous times throughout the 2 tables

Comment: got this to work?

Comment: It seems to be working ok, the speed in practice is a bit of a issue though

Comment: true, but all constructs you can use will be quirky and slow; update to PostGIS 2.5, splitting polygons by multilines is now supported!

Comment: Your question is unclear. You say you want to split the polygon into multiple polygons, but the image you provide shows a set of multiple linestrings that don't for individual polygons.

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

Starting with PostGIS 2.5 [`ST_Split`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Split.html) supports splitting *Polygons* by *MultiLinestrings*.

---

This is actually expected behavior; `ST_Split` doesn't support splitting *(Multi)Polygons* by *MultiLinestrings*, and with your query you will get split parts of the same polygon for every intersecting line.

A possible workaround could be to use a recursive query and repeatedly split the collection by a single line:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
    split AS (
        SELECT (SELECT MAX(<id>) FROM blades) AS line_id,
               ST_Collect(a.geom) AS geom
        FROM large_polygon AS a
        UNION ALL
        SELECT line_id - 1 AS line_id,
               ST_Split(a.geom, b.geom) AS geom
        FROM split AS a,
             blade AS b
        WHERE b.<id> = a.line_id
    )

SELECT (ST_Dump(geom)).geom
FROM split
WHERE line_id = 0;
```

This will need your `blade` to have a consecutive row number (`<id>`) starting with `1` (I wrote this from the top of my head, there might be room for conceptual improvement).

---

As you mention 'large polygon' and seeing your images, it seems you are aiming at reducing size? If so, consider using [`ST_SubDivide`](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Subdivide.html); you may need to adjust the `max_vertices` parameter to fit your needs.